# I face a functional anomaly during this code execution. what's the problem?

Tags: function, callback, chain

It's the sample code of what I was doing. My intention was to receive an object within a callback but ended up as undefined.

Code:

```
const a = message => console.log(message);
const b = mes => a(mes);
const c = cb => cb();
const greeting = () => c(() => b("good morning"));
console.log(greeting());
```

Output:
"good morning"
undefined